# Looping through files with spaces in filenames

Tags: loops, unix, concatenation, filenames, cat

I have the following block of code that loops through files.

```
SOURCEDIR = /source/path
TARGETDIR = /target/path
FILEOUT   = file.out

list_files=`ls $SOURCEDIR `;
echo -e "File list: "$list_files;

for files in ${list_files}
do
        echo -e "File loading: "$files;
        cat ${SOURCEDIR}/${files} >> ${TARGETDIR}/${FILEOUT}
done;
```

I'm trying to concatenate all files found in a path into one file.

The problem is when a file has spaces in its filename, the script fails because the loop reads each word from the filename as one separated file. Even if I put `"$files"` in quotes, result is the same.

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this complex loop for that. `cat /path/to/files/* > /path/to/result` will do just fine.